# Decompressing string

Tags: python, python-2.7, decoding, run-length-encoding

I am receiving string in the form of `a3b4x2` which needs to be decompressed to get `aaabbbbxx`.If the digits are fixed, such as this example, it is easy to decompress. However, the input can come in the form of `a1192x12` which needs to decompressed to get `aaaaaaaaaaa99xxxxxxxxxxxx` or in the form of `31142` to get `3333333333344`. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: It is not possible because it's ambiguous. How could you distinguish 11 times "a" + 2 times "9" from 1192 times "a"?

Comment: That is my challenge.

Comment: Or even 1 "a" followed by 92 "1"s. You want any solution or all or how do you want to disambiguate?

Comment: Perhaps there's some limit on the "counts" like max two digits (99).

Comment: @IonutTicus that could have saved my day. But I don't see such patterns from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the number of occurence of a letter in one or two digits (not more),
you can use the following regular expression to find couples of the form lettre + number:
`r"(\w)(\d{1,2})"`.

Here is a possible solution:

```py
import re

samples = ["a3b4x2", "a1192x12", "31142"]

for sample in samples:
    result = ""
    for couple in re.findall(r"(\w)(\d{1,2})", sample):
        letter, number = couple
        number = int(number)
        result += letter * number
    print(result)
```

You get:

```
aaabbbbxx
aaaaaaaaaaa99xxxxxxxxxxxx
3333333333344
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves a large chunk of strings but not all. I will accept your solution though.